# Cardshifter web client deploy script

Tags: javascript, node.js

The [Cardshifter web client](https://github.com/Cardshifter/HTML-Client) is coming along! The game client is a web app written mostly in Angular.js and is hosted at at [play.cardshifter.com](http://play.cardshifter.com/).

@SimonForsberg (who runs the server) is getting tired of the web people always working tirelessly and updating the code, and asked for a script that can do deployment for him.

#### Requirements

- Upload the contents of `dist/` to `/assets/` and `www/` to `/` through FTP.
- Post a message to the chat bot [Duga](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/51786/duga) using a HTTP request when done.
- Can be run automatically on [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org).

#### Background

I'm quite new to JavaScript and Node.js land. I chose to still use it for three reasons:

1. Dependency management already set up with Npm
2. Project is already JavaScript; easier maintenance
3. Fun to learn :)

I chose to pass credentials through environment variables because it looks like Travis CI handles [encrypted variables](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Encrypted-Variables) well. A person that has the credentials can also set up a simple script to run the deployment with those specific variables.

@skiwi told me about promises after having written the code originally, but it prompted me to convert the code to use them instead of normal callbacks. I think this lead to a great improvement of the readability of the code.

`ftp-deploy` was acting up when uploading `dist/` and `www/` separately, which is why the script is now first copying everything to a temporary directory with a structure emulating the server. One problem was that if `remoteRoot` didn't exist, the upload would fail.

Simon hasn't told me the address of the FTP server yet, which is why I left `localhost:2121` in there.

```
/* Deploy the client to play.cardshifter.com
 *
 * How to use:
 *  1. Build the project and make sure that everything is in order.
 *  2. Set up environment variables (see below).
 *  3. Run `npm run deploy`.
 *  4. Profit!
 *
 * Environment variables used:
 *  - DEPLOY_FTP_USERNAME: Username used to log in through FTP.
 *  - DEPLOY_FTP_PASSWORD: Password used to log in through FTP.
 *  - DEPLOY_DUGA_KEY: Duga API key. If not set the chat bot post is skipped.
 */
'use strict';

var copy = require('recursive-copy');
var FtpDeploy = require('ftp-deploy');
var path = require('path');
var request = require('request-promise');
var temp = require('temp').track();

function ftpConfig(local, remote) {
    return {
        username: process.env.DEPLOY_FTP_USERNAME,
        password: process.env.DEPLOY_FTP_PASSWORD,
        host: "localhost",
        port: 2121,
        localRoot: local,
        remoteRoot: remote
    };
};

var chatBotRequest = {
    apiKey: process.env.DEPLOY_DUGA_KEY,
    roomId: 16134,
    text: "New web client version uploaded to http://play.cardshifter.com/."
};

var chatBotConfig = {
    url: "http://stats.zomis.net/GithubHookSEChatService/bot/jsonPost",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
}

function postToChat(config, botRequest) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var json = JSON.stringify(botRequest, ["apiKey", "roomId", "text"]);
        config.headers["Content-Length"] = json.length;
        config.body = json;

        request(config)
        .then(function(body) {
            resolve(body);
        })
    });
}

function setupFiles() {
    // ftp-deploy doesn't handle uploading from multiple directories well
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        temp.mkdir("cardshifter-deploy", function (err, tempDir) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }

            Promise.all([
                copy(path.join(__dirname, "..", "www"), tempDir),
                copy(path.join(__dirname, "..", "dist"), path.join(tempDir, "assets"))
            ])
            .then(function() {
                resolve(tempDir);
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                reject(err);
            });
        });
    });
}

function deployFtp(config) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        new FtpDeploy().deploy(config, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve();
            }
        });
    });
}

setupFiles()
.then(function(dir) {
    var config = ftpConfig(dir, "/");
    console.log("Deploying to ftp://" + config.host + ":" + config.port + "...");
    return deployFtp(config);
})
.then(function() {
    console.log("FTP deployment successful.");
    if (chatBotRequest.apiKey) {
        console.log("Posting message to " + chatBotConfig.url + "...");
        return postToChat(chatBotConfig, chatBotRequest);
    }
})
.then(function(responseBody) {
    if (responseBody) {
        console.log(responseBody);
    }
})
.catch(function(err) {
    console.error("Error: " + err);
});
```

Comment: Why don't you guys use Amazon S3 for static assets? It's not free but it's cheap enough to essentially be free (something crazy like 0.9c for 10k requests)

Comment: One other thing you might look into is `gulp`. Particularly as it has modules for [ftp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-deploy-ftp), and all of the related stuff there. I'm not familiar with Duga though, so I can't help much there.

Comment: Server address? Try `play.cardshifter.com` ;)

Answer (score 5):

There's a few points you could improve on, but for the most part, your code looks good.

---

Funny memes are funny, but, don't belong in comments :-(

> ```
>  * How to use:
>  *  1. Build the project and make sure that everything is in order.
>  *  2. Set up environment variables (see below).
>  *  3. Run `npm run deploy`.
>  *  4. Profit!
> ```

On a related note, this kinda thing probably belongs in one of the readme.md files, or a GitHub wiki page for the web client.

---

You can actually omit the `var`s when you declare a few at once:

> ```
> var copy = require('recursive-copy');
> var FtpDeploy = require('ftp-deploy');
> var path = require('path');
> var request = require('request-promise');
> var temp = require('temp').track();
> ```

Which can become:

```
var copy = require('recursive-copy'),
    FtpDeploy = require('ftp-deploy'),
    path = require('path'),
    request = require('request-promise'),
    temp = require('temp').track();
```

Although, this can be dangerous if you forget the commas, as they can rise through the function to find a higher-level variable declaration, and become global in the process. [You can read about that here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2485439/3296811).

---

You shouldn't have random magic numbers/spells everywhere, use a spellbook (define them) instead.

> ```
>     host: "localhost",
>     port: 2121
>     roomId: 16134,
> ```

Or, make them parameters for input.

---

Remember that the chatrooms you're sending messages to support Markdown, it's best to use it.

> ```
> text: "New web client version uploaded to http://play.cardshifter.com/."
> ```

into:

```
text: "New web client version uploaded to [play.cardshifter.com](http://play.cardshifter.com/)."
```

---

Consider using `.join`s in future, also, JavaScript's string concatenation is a bit *slow*. Array joins run a bit faster, and let you use specified 'glue' also.

> ```
> console.log("Deploying to ftp://" + config.host + ":" + config.port + "...");
> ```

---

Do you need to include the `Content-Length` header in the API request?

Probably not.

> ```
>     config.headers["Content-Length"] = json.length;
> ```

---

The following could be a ternary:

> ```
>         if (err) {
>             reject(err);
>         } else {
>             resolve();
>         }
> ```

which can turn into:

```
err ? reject(err) : resolve();
```

Comment: Are `host`, `port` and `roomId` really that magic? They're not *everywhere*: I put all configuration in easy to edit objects at the top of the file.

Comment: Well, the `roomId` is pretty magic, the others are somewhat magic

Comment: Is there a reason why you would omit variable declarations? In my opinion it makes it harder to read and harder to add more variables. As you might forget to overlook the `;` and `,`.

Comment: Don't omit `var`. It's harder to maintain and arguably doesn't improve readability at all. This is especially true with ES6 around the corner, where you distinguish between `const` and `let`.

Comment: I'd disagree about funny comments. If they're used sparingly, like in this case, I'd say they're okay.

Comment: I really wouldn't say they're okay. And in this case the 'Profit' meme is pointless, well, it's basically always pointless

Comment: I'm sorry, but I must disagree with this review because it is 99% unnecessary stylistic comments, and I disagree with a few of them.